# Solve an array of linear equation systems with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have an m×n array of linear equation systems (same LHS, different RHS:es). Is there an easy way of passing these to `numpy.linalg.solve` in a single call?

In more detail, I have

- one left-hand side: a single ndarray, shape (3, 3)
- m×n right-hand sides as one ndarray, shape (m, n, 3)

and I would like m×n solutions, also as an (m, n, 3) ndarray.

I *can* do this in a single call, by re-arranging the RHS:es to shape (3, mn), and then re-arranging the result:

```
res = numpy.linalg.solve(LHS, RHS.transpose([2, 0, 1]).reshape(3, -1))\
                  .reshape(3, m, -1).transpose([1, 2, 0])
```

but that is rather a lot of juggling. The docs for `numpy.linalg.solve` mentions broadcasting, but I frankly don’t understand what it’s trying to tell me...

Answer (score 0):

As what the docs said, you can use broadcasting to solve multiple systems of linear equations in a single call to numpy.linalg.solve.

Reshape the right-hand sides RHS to (3, m, n). This will make it so that the first dimension (index 0) corresponds to the variables in the system, the second dimension (index 1) corresponds to the different systems, and the third dimension (index 2) corresponds to the different right-hand sides for each system.

You cna then use the numpy.linalg.solve function with the reshaped RHS and the LHS as the arguments. Since LHS has shape (3, 3) and RHS has shape (3, m, n), the solution array will have shape (3, m, n), which is what you want.

```py
import numpy as np

# Define the left-hand side
LHS = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])

# Define the right-hand sides
RHS = np.array([[[10, 20], [30, 40]], [[50, 60], [70, 80]], [[90, 100], [110, 120]]])

# Reshape RHS to (3, m, n)
RHS = RHS.transpose([2, 0, 1])

# Solve the systems
solutions = np.linalg.solve(LHS, RHS)

print(solutions)  # prints the solutions for each system
```

Comment: Passing the LHS as (3,3) and the RHS as (3, 256, 256) gives me: `ValueError: solve: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (m,m),(m,n)->(m,n) (size 256 is different from 3)`

Comment: LHS has shape (3, 3), which is a square matrix, but RHS has shape (3, 256, 256), which has a different number of rows (3) and columns (256*256) than LHS. This is why you are seeing the "mismatch in its core dimension 0" error.

You can either reshape RHS to have the same number of columns as LHS (e.g., (3, 3, 256*256)), or you can use a different approach to solve your system of linear equations. For example, you could use the numpy.linalg.lstsq function, which can solve linear least squares problems with multiple right-hand sides.